# Matlab Defining A Function That Has Vector As An Input

Tags: matlab, function, input, vector

I was given a simple exercise by my professor, which is to define a cerrtain function. Here is my function

```
function [a,b,c] = PHUN([x,y],[z,t,w])

a = x
b = ((y+z)^2)*t 
c = z/w + x
```

However, matlab states that I am using invalid syntax in the first line. So, I figured, perhaps there is a particular way in which vector inputs are supposed to be typed. I have attempt several searches on defining functions with vector inputs (or arguments), but have not been successful. I was wondering if someone could possibly help me.

Comment: See [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html) for some information on matlab variables (matrices and arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass vectors as arguments in the same way you pass variables. Then access them in the function body appropriately. Your function could be re-written as follows:

```
function [a,b,c] = PHUN(X,Y)

a = X(1)
b = ((X(2)+Y(1))^2)*Y(2) 
c = Y(1)/Y(3) + X(1)
```

Or if you want to keep the original variables:

```
function [a,b,c] = PHUN(X,Y)

Z = num2cell([X,Y]);
[x,y,z,t,w] = Z{:};

a = x
b = ((y+z)^2)*t 
c = z/w + x
```

Comment: Oh, very interesting. When matlab encounters the first line, does it know whether X and Y are vectors, or not until it reaches the lines below?

Comment: I think it would know the moment it reaches first line. But I am not too sure, you can post another question or wait for some time before you get a better answer.

Comment: MATLAB actually treats even a scalar as a `1x1` matrix, according to me.

Comment: they may be cells for example, objects, structs, it doesn't matter.. MATLAB doesn't *compile*.. if anything is wrong you may notice at runtime. This is rather annoying sometimes.

Comment: If `x`,`y`,`w`,`t` and `z` are meaningful symbols for your equations then you might want to consider starting your function with `x = X(1);`, `y = X(2);`, `z = Y(1)` etc and then you can use the equations from the code in your question (e.g. `c = z/w + t` instead of `Y(1)/Y(3) + X(1)`. This might make it more readable.